# How can check string value that contain in main string value in array by javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check user.uid that contain or not in combined user ids.
here is combined ids in arrays

```
getid Array [
  "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
  "KgRwTDgenjYpODPxRaldDQy9nnH36Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
  "pNv0iKlZ6xVOl0fFOZSoXJoPuVx2E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe2",
]
```

here is user.uid

```
pNv0iKlZ6xVOl0fFOZSoXJoPuVx2
```

I want to get result is my user.uid is in or not in this combined Id arrays.

```
const uid = user.uid in getId ? yes : no
```

(or ) how can check this condition .I not know.
I not want to remove my user.uid from combined id , I just want to check my user.uid is in or not in this combined Id.
can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check using array functions like `filter`, `find` , `findIndex`, `some`

```js
let array = [
  "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
  "KgRwTDgenjYpODPxRaldDQy9nnH36Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",
  "pNv0iKlZ6xVOl0fFOZSoXJoPuVx2E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe2",
];

let userId = 'pNv0iKlZ6xVOl0fFOZSoXJoPuVx2';

const exist = array.filter(id => id.includes(userId)).length > 0;

//Using some method

const exist1 = array.some(id => id.includes(userId));

console.log(exist, exist1);
```

Comment: some() is simpler than filter and doesn't require creating a new array

Comment: Updated the code with some method, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get a boolean value indicating if element is in the array or not, you can simply use `getId.includes(user.uid)`.
Check out this [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) if want to know more about `Array.prototype.includes()`

```js
const arr = [  "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",  "KgRwTDgenjYpODPxRaldDQy9nnH36Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2",  "pNv0iKlZ6xVOl0fFOZSoXJoPuVx2E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe2",
]

const invalidId = 'pNv0iKlZ6xVOl0fFOZSoXJoPuVx2'
const validId = "E8R52y6dD8XI3shXhnhS9pVzUpe26Lf5bHwzCSbI2bmoMv7KuduMGwe2"

const arrayHasInvalidId = arr.includes(invalidId)
const arrayHasValidId = arr.includes(validId)


console.log(arrayHasInvalidId,arrayHasValidId);
```